# passing-bash-variable-to-curl quotes

Tags: php, bash, curl

I have some problems with a part of my cript, it's answering by showing the PHP code of my target page.
Here is the part of my code:

```
curl -X POST -F 'decription='$description'' -F 'valeur=007' -F 'nom_carte=something' -F 'horodatage=something' $cible
```

I think it's a quoting pb. I tried possibilities but still don't get it.

Comment: `"description='$description'"`?

Comment: More likely `description="$description"`

Comment: If you're seeing the PHP source code, the problem is on the server, not your `curl` command.

Comment: I'm with @Barmar. It looks like you may also have a quoting problem, but more fundamentally the server should *never* send the source code, no matter what malformed query comes down the wire.